# How to execute a Java program using button click even written in VBA

Tags: java, vba, excel

How to execute a Java program using button click even written in VBA. I have a scenario to give call to Selenium TestNG class using onClick event from VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Java program is executed normally as a command line. Example:

```
java MainClass
```

VBA supports execution of commands using WScript.Shell.

Hence, you should create an object of WScript.Shell and then call the Run method with command line argument as given above.

Please ensure that Java exists in PATH. Below is a sample code:

```
Dim winshell As Object
Set winshell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitReturn As Boolean: waitReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

winshell.Run "java MainClass", windowStyle, waitReturn
```